# How to set max date in range as default selected date in the Android Date Picker

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-datepicker

In a hybrid app, the date pickers maximum and minimum dates have been calculated in javascript. On Android, when the date picker is launched, the date selected by default is the minimum date calculated in Javascript side. However, the requirement is to show the maximum date calculated. How to achieve this? Is there any setting in AndroidManifest that will help to achieve this. The implementation is in cordova 6.

Comment: see this link..https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-okaybmd-date-picker-plugin